# How to do a VLookup loop

Tags: vba, excel

I tried search google and with the proposed codes, but still couldn't work out the VLookup.

I have two workbook, one is ActiveWorkbook, the other is Template.xls (with the lookup worksheet name "CtyAccesCode" in range A1:B13).

What I want to do is if a cell in column AD is ***NOT*** empty, then use VLookup in another cell in column AB at the same row to find a correspondent.

Below is what I used, but Excel doesn't give a value after I run this code:

```
For Each cell In Range("H2:H" & LastRow)    ' This is the lookup range
    If IsEmpty(Range("AD" & i).Value) = False Then    ' This finds out if cell in AD is empty
        Cells(i, 28) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell, _
        Workbooks("Template.xls").Worksheets("CtyAccesCode") _
    .Range("A1:B13"), 2, 0)    ' This puts the find out value in cells in column AB or 28
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: could you please upload the full code here

Comment: Why `IsEmpty(Range("AD" & i).Value) = False`? That is the opposite of what you've descriibed.

Comment: Sorry, I omitted the "Not" in my original description, what I want is if cell is not empty, then another cell same row will use vlookup. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `i`? Shouldn't it be `cell.row`? Also it would be much easier if you use objects and then work with that. See this code (**Untested**)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wbThis As Workbook, wbThat As Workbook
    Dim wsThis As Worksheet, wsThat As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range

    Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook
    '~~> Let's say this is the sheet where you want the result
    '~~> Change name as applicable
    Set wsThis = wbThis.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Change path as applicable
    Set wbThat = Workbooks.Open("C:\Template.xls")
    Set wsThat = wbThat.Sheets("CtyAccesCode")

    With wsThis
        For Each aCell In .Range("H2:H" & LastRow)
            If Len(Trim(.Range("AD" & aCell.Row).Value)) <> 0 Then
                .Cells(aCell.Row, 28) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
                                        aCell.Value, wsThat.Range("A1:B13"), 2, 0)
            End If
        Next aCell
    End With

    wbThat.Close (False)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick :

```
For Each cell In Range("H2:H" & LastRow)    ' This is the lookup range
    If IsEmpty(Range("AD" & cell.Row).Value) = False Then    ' This finds out if cell in AD is empty
        Cells(i, 28) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("AD" & cell.Row), _
                Workbooks("Template.xls").Worksheets("CtyAccesCode") _
                .Range("A1:B13"), 2, 0)    ' This puts the find out value in cells in column AB or 28
    Else
        Cells(i, 28) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("AB" & cell.Row), _
                Workbooks("Template.xls").Worksheets("CtyAccesCode") _
                .Range("A1:B13"), 2, 0)    ' This puts the find out value in cells in column AB or 28
    End If
Next cell
```